# Trouble with Vagrant - "404 - Not Found"

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox, lamp, portforwarding

I am attempting to make a LAMP box using Vagrant. I have been told that it is quite simple to use. I am completely new to networks and virtual machines and have very little experience with Linux/Ubuntu. I have currently tried following the tutorial on the official documentation page: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/networking.html.

I have gotten up to the networking article in the documentation and can't seem to get it working.

Now the problem is, due to my inexperience with networking and linux based OS's I have no idea where to begin trouble shooting. I will try to give as much information I can.

I'm running the latest version of Vagrant with the latest version of Virtualbox with Windows 8.1.

As per the tutorial, my current Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80
end
```

My bootstrap.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -f /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

When I went to http://127.0.0.1:4567, it displayed an error page containing this message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
===================================================
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 4567
```

I would rather not edit any config files, unless there was an explanation, as I feel that would be a workaround. But regardless, ANY help would be appreciated. If I need to open up a port, then how do  I'm at the point where I'm just considering using XAMPP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had same problem. I tried to restart apache from the vagrant box, I got following warning on my terminal.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2   

AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html] does not exist
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified 
domain name, using 10.0.2.15. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Create a DocumentRoot to fix the 404 issue by creating a directory called `/var/www/html`

Comment: tldr: Create html folder

Comment: Thanks Ruben. Yes , I forget create html folder , After create it, everything ok!

Answer (score 9):

The issue is on `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` 000-default file.

Apache2 is pointing to `var/www/html` and vagrant example to `var/www` just remove de /html and make a `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you access your web server from inside your virtual machine ?

For example, try  `curl localhost:80`

if curl is not installed, use `sudo apt-get install curl` on Ubuntu and try again.

Also, have you checked your apache virtual hosts ?
Is there a 000-default file in /etc/apache2/sites-available ?

Comment: I actually get the same exact not found message from inside the host. There is no 000-default but there are 2 other default files.

Comment: can you paste the result of ```ls -ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled``` ?

Comment: It's actually working now. Thank you for your help. Out of curiosity if it wasn't appearing, what would you have assumed?

Comment: I was thinking that there was an issue in your virtualhosts files.
Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in `bootstrap.sh`

1. You need start the web service. You can also `vagrant ssh` to manually start it
2. You need make soft link, not hard link.

So the script will be updated as

```
$ cat bootstrap.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -s /vagrant /var/www
fi

service apache2 start
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. But what is a soft link and a hard link?

Comment: If you don't know what is soft link and hard link, then read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link

Comment: and the fix does work, you need review your environment before make this conclusion.

Comment: Oh you're right! It worked. I just didn't copy down the bootstrap.sh file correctly. I'm really just confused as to why I have to modify the Vagrantfile in this way for it to work. In theory, according to the official tutorial, this should work "out of the box." Did they give me broken code? What is it about my platform that requires me to change these settings. I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: Do you have any tips or leads at the very least?

Comment: keep looking for the answer by yourself. In fact, I am not sure what you are talking in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81143/discussion-between-dimi-and-bmw).

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented two working solutions:

The first is to change the file **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** modifing **DocumentRoot** in `/var/www` instead of `/var/www/html`

The second is to change the **Vagrant** file `bootstrap.sh` in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www/html ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www/html
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www/html
fi
```

Beside that, for some reason I've had to change also the configuration of port forwarding in the **Vagrantfile**, adding the host_ip key, like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
end
```