# How do I troubleshoot a 404 page with my first Vagrant setup?

Tags: vagrant

My problem is identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960478/trouble-with-vagrant-404-not-found) person's, except I'm using ubuntu/trusty64. I get a 404 page when I go to localhost:4567.

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
end
```

bootstrap.sh:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

These are straight from the setup guide. I also tried this from one of the answers there:

```
$ cat bootstrap.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -s /vagrant /var/www
fi

service apache2 start
```

and ran `vagrant reload`, as well as `vagrant reload --provision` when that didn't work. This is what `curl localhost:80` returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL / was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Could it be that I don't have ssh working from command prompt? Git and cygwin are in my system and user path but I still get the ssh executable not found error. Putty works though. Using Windows 8.1, Vagrant 1.7.4, VirtualBox 5.0.6.

Comment: apache is installed and tells you you have no file to display - do you have index.html ? file would be at same level as Vagrantfile per your setting

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I do have index.html. I ended up dual booting and installing vagrant on Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.3 and am running into the same problem. `vagrant ssh` works now though, which is nice. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The default web directory of apache isn't `/var/www` anymore. It is `/var/www/html`. As far as I know it was `/var/www` sometimes in the past. Probably the Vagrant tutorial is from these days.

To make this work you have to alter the `bootstrap.sh` to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www/html ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www/html
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www/html
fi
```

Then it works! You don't need to start apache2 explicitly. apache2 starts automatically after installation.